# Android Heat Map

Tags: android, android-maps

I am trying to create a heat map for android app like this:

[image]

I found a example on Google Maps API [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-heatmap), but i am not sure with it is the best way, can you give me a light?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google launched recently the new *Google Maps Android API Utility Library* allowing to create easily heatmaps. Take a look the [BlogPost](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/marker-clustering-and-heatmaps-new.html) and the [Google Maps V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/heatmap) documentation.

Also, the source code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) with some sample code available.

Comment: If you consider the answer is good for you, please accept it to close the question. Thanks